# Cannot properly install ant using phonegap, windows 7 and android SDK

Tags: cordova, ant, path, cmd

I am trying to start developing a phonegap app, but unfortunately every time I try to run the following command "cordova platform add android" I get this error "Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.". Here is how I have set up ant and everything that has something to do with phonegap development in PATH.

Variable                                      Value

ANDROID_HOME                        C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk 
ANT_HOME                                  C:\Development\apache-ant-1.9.4 
JAVA_HOME                                C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05 
PATH                                           C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm;%JAVA_HOME%
                                                     \bin;%ANT_HOME\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-                                                                                              tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;

Comment: what output do you get with `ant -version` in `command-prompt` ?

Comment: "'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- download `apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.zip` from here: http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi
- **unzip** the `ant zip` into the folder `C:\Development`. this will automatically create the following folder: `C:\Development\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin` with the contents of the **.zip** inside this folder.
- either change your `ANT_HOME` to `C:\Development\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4` **OR** browse to `C:\Development\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin`, *cut* the folder `apache-ant-1.9.4` and *paste* it directly under `C:\Development` so that the `/bin, /lib, /ect ..` folders are directly under `C:\Development\apache-ant-1.9.4`.
- now when you run `ant -version` in the `command-prompt` it should return the `Ant version` installed on your system.

Comment: is there a `bin` folder directly under `C:\Development\apache-ant-1.9.4` ?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot for your help man, I noticed a semicolon missing between the paths somewhere. Now everything is great, sorry for your time and thanks a lot :)